# Is there a limit to how many lotions and perfumes one can pack on a checked luggage for an international flight? I plan on gifting them

Tags: luggage, international-travel

16 lotions and 13 perfumes. Will it cause any trouble for being too many?

Comment: You may want to add where you are going to/from on which airline. But as far as I can remember as long as it is not flammable you can put any liquid in your checked in luggage. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from Customs, nobody cares how many perfumes you put in your checked luggage. As long as you fulfill the declaration requirements at the source or destination.  You may very well have to pay duties/taxes on your import if they exceed your duty free allowance at the destination.

Fair use policy still applies. Perfumes are flammable mostly and you can’t just pack a big bunch of them without raising some eyebrows. Whether 16 bottles are too many can only be reliably answered if you mention where is the flight originating from and what’s the destination and possibly the airline.

Comment: And the size of each... 13 x 30 ml is not quite the same as 13 x 300 ml. You mightt want to emphasise that taxes and duties may need to be paid if the value exceeds the duty-free allowances.

Comment: And the duty-free allowance is typically N ml, you can have those in 1 or 100 bottles if you like.

Comment: I may have missed that one, but duty-free allowances in litres are usually for (drinkable) alcohol. Here the allowance will more probably be linked to the value of the items brought in, expressed in the local currency. Some perfumes can be quite expensive, so 13 of the larger ones will certainly exceed allowances in most countries.

Comment: 29 bottles could also lead them to conclude you're importing them for resale, which could trigger different rules than ordinary personal use imports by travelers.

Comment: Just because you say you are going to gift them doesn't mean you will be believed.